# Primitive type HashSet or HashMap 10 times faster than Object?

Tags: performance, dart, hashmap, hashset, primitive

**Update:** This should be considered a bug in flutter channel stable v1.9.1+hotfix.4. When switched to channel master this is fixed, int and Object Sets have performances of the same order of magnitude.

A benchmark throws that `HashSet<int>` performs an average of 10 times faster than `HashSet<Object>`.
What is the reason of this behavior?

I was having a big performance drop (over an order of magnitude) when I changed the internals of a library in a way that I expected to be more efficient.

The problem was changing from a `HashSet<int>` to a `HashSet<MyClass>`, which I confirmed when running the simple benchmark in a HashSet that adds the same value 1000 times. The result is that `HashSet<int>` performs an average of 10 times faster than `HashSet<Object>`.

Any suggestions from a code design perspective? The code looks much cleaner when having a `HashSet<MyClass>` instead of having additional data structures that relate the instances to an int. This performance drop is important since it's the core of the library. The only way I have found to keep the program efficient, is to manipulate everything with an integer that identifies MyClass.

The benchmark can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/icatalud/dc28bd3bdd7c13b39c308b7abb9a9d8c

The function that adds to the Set is the following:

```dart
plainAddSet<T>(T obj, [int n = 1000]) {
  var s = Set<T>();
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    s.add(obj);
  }
}
```

**Update:** Running more tests led me to the root cause of the performance drop. The hashCode getter is extremely slow. In the following class if the hashCode method is not overriden, it takes 20 times longer, even slower than Object. Otherwise it takes slightly more than an int Set.

```dart
class Identifiable {
  static int lastId = 0;
  int id;
  Identifiable() : id = lastId++;

  // Not overriding this getter, causes the benchmark to take 20 times longer.
  int get hashCode => id;

  bool operator ==(other) =>
      other.runtimeType == runtimeType &&
      hashCode == other.hashCode;
}
```

**Update 2:** Still, it would be interesting to understand why overriding the == operator and accessing the hashCode from there is three times slower than leaving the Object default implementation (which is more than 10 times slower than int).

```dart
class Identifiable {
  bool operator ==(other) =>
      other.runtimeType == runtimeType &&
      other.hashCode == hashCode;
}
```

**Update 3:** There is an [open issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24206) about this in the dart SDK repository. It has been there for over 4 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested with different class implementations and can see the waiting time are for hashCode. This makes sense since the hashCode for an integer are just the same integer as it represent (makes sense if you think about it).

The hashCode for Object() are more complicated and needs to make an external call into some code I don't know.

If I create my own class and override the hashCode property with something like "always return 5" then I get the same speed as the integer.

Since hashCode (and ==) are being used every time you add something to a Map or Set, it is important to keep this two functions as efficient as possible.

**Answer to Update 2**

The reason why the Object() hashCode property are slower is because it does a lot than the integer hashCode. I have checked the source code and this is the steps it does:

- The hashCode implementation are patched in here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/e88057fe04deccb9468d93785f3fd43523c2f91f/sdk_nnbd/lib/_internal/vm/lib/object_patch.dart#L41
- Which ends up calling a static method called _objectHashCode: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/7c1821c4aae86db4febf3c0656985e23df31be0f/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/object_patch.dart#L25
- The first thing _objectHashCode does it calling an external method by calling _setHash. The implementation of this can be found here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/84db16381d8efbb4fdbcfa79ef411a5ec8809bc7/runtime/lib/object.cc#L34

As you can see this is a lot more complicated than just taking the value of the integer itself and use that as the hash. As you also can see in the code there are even usage of Random generators.

I should add, that the Hash are cached so it is only the first time calling hashCode it is really slow. But as you can see the cached version are still an external call which are more expensive than just getting an integer variable.

**Update for "Proposing a workaround to this issue"**

This is happening in flutter channel stable v1.9.1+hotfix.4, but is fixed in master. It shouldn't be necessary to implement in the next Flutter releases.

If you can't accept the performance of the standard hashCode method right now, I think the only other way is to manually cache it like:

```
class ObjectWithCachedHash {
  int _hashCodeCache;

  @override
  int get hashCode => _hashCodeCache ??= super.hashCode;
}
```

This should only be done if the hashCode are not dependent on any values inside the object (e.g. the standard hashCode implementation which are purely instance based).

**Updated with link to issue**

The problem with slowish hashCode is a know issue (thanks Ignacio Catalan for pointing that out):

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24206

It should be noted that the performance problem found in this stackoverflow question are more likely related to a recent regression there has been fixed on master:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24206#issuecomment-539448012

But the fix for this regression will only fix the issue for x64, so 32 bit architectures (and properly also all ARM architectures) will still be affected by the performance issue (which are another issue which are not related to the regression).

So the recommendation for 32bit and ARM users would be to locally cache the hashCode value if you code depends on the Object.hashCode and are going to make a lot comparisons (e.g. using Map's or Set's with larger amount of objects).

Comment: I got to the same conclusion, but still it's strange that the hashCode takes 10 times longer. Strings take double time of int (reasonable), same with any class that overrides the hashCode operator. I cannot get same time as int as you posted. I get the same performance if the hashCode returns a constant or a variable int, it's always same as String performance, which is about twice as slow to integers.

Comment: Other funny behavior is that overriding the == operator with any implementation that uses the hashCode getter, reduces the performance by 2 o 3 times compared to not overriding the method.

Comment: You implementation of Identifiable (in update 2) is a little problematic since it makes it so == always returns false (in most cases since hashCode is not 5 in all tests) which changes the whole logic of the program (now it adds to the set/map each time so the set/map has to grow). Try instead:

class Identifiable {
  static int lastId = 0;
  int id;
  Identifiable() : id = lastId++;

  // Not overriding this getter, causes the benchmark to take 20 times longer.
  int get hashCode => id;

  bool operator ==(other) =>
      other is Identifiable &&
          id == other.id;
}

Comment: Updated my answer with some details about the Object.hashCode implementation.

Comment: Thank you for investigating and your thoroughly explanation @julenmand101, but don't you think there is some implementation issue that should be addressed? If the hash is cached in dart like: ```int _storedHash;
  int get hashCode {
    _storedHash ??= super.hashCode;
    return _storedHash;
  }```
it works fast. Why is it cached externally if it is taking 10 times longer, when using code like that fixes it so easily?

Comment: Well, this is out of the scope of stackoverflow I think. Instead you should fill out an issue on Dart SDK GitHub: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues

Comment: But again, you would often implement you own logic for HashCode and == since you often want that two objects are the same if they contains the same informations (instead of saying they are only the same if they are the same instance). But yes, I find it a little odd that the Object.hashCode are not cached inside the Dart runtime.

Comment: I disagree, normally you dont implement your own logic for hashCode, but now that I know this, I will start doing it, which is a bit absurd.
I think there is two things missing to answer the question completely:
1. Proposing a workaround to this issue (like caching or creating a new hash)
2. Get to the bottom of the subject. You pointed out the external code that retrieves the hash, but there is no explanation about why this external function should take so long. External implementations are usually faster. Primitives types, Set, Map, etc, are fast.

Comment: Well, in lot of cases you want two objects to be consider equal if they contains the exact same information (but are still two different object instances). And if you override ==, you should also override hashCode. I have updated my answer with a workaround for your specific case. About "Get to the bottom of the subject" this should again really be an issue on the Dart SDK bug tracker since I am not a Dart developer. Do you want to create an issue? Or do you want me to do it?

Comment: What I mean by getting to the bottom, is in terms of reasoning. You pointed out the code that is executing, but you didn't provide a justification for having such an odd implementation. From a common sense point of view, this is very odd, it's not acceptable that a basic data structure has a performance drop of 10x like that on, unless there is a really good reason for it.
I did post in an existing issue in the Dart SDK and this was indeed a bug. By the way are you also getting the 10x perforamnce drop when you run the benchmark? In flutter channel master this is fixed.

Comment: I would give an up arrow to your answer, but I do not have the reputation to do so. I will not mark it as the final answer, because the answer missed a deeper reflection on the issue. This is in fact a bug.

Comment: It looks like the "deeper reflection on the issue" can be found in the Dart SDK issue you have found. I can add a reference to that but I don't think it adds much value to copy all the content from that issue into my answer.

Comment: The answer as it is closes the question, I will mark it as the answer, but please add an explanation that this is still currently an issue in 32 bit machines. People that is writing Dart code for 32 bit machines should know that they must override hashCode if they attempt to use it.

Comment: Added details about the problem are still relevant for 32 bit (and ARM) architectures (I have also tested with latest dev-build that the problem are fixed for x64 and still relevant for x86). :)